# cannot read properties of undefined (reading rpc )

Tags: javascript, testing, anchor, solana, anchor-solana

i am trying to run a test for the flip of the bool value but getting this error while testing it

this is my code

```
  it('Creates a Flipper', async () => {

    const switchAccount = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
    console.log(switchAccount.publicKey.toBase58())
    await program.rpc.initialize({
      accounts: {
        switchAccount: switchAccount.publicKey,
        user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
        system_program: SystemProgram.programId,
      },
      signers: [switchAccount],
    }); //Create RPC Closed
```

and this is the eroor i am getting

```
  0 passing (11ms)
  2 failing

  1) light
       Creates a Flipper:
     TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rpc')
      at Context.<anonymous> (tests/light.js:16:19)
      at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)
```

Comment: The error is saying `program` is undefined. Where is that initialized?

Answer (score 0):

```
  const anchor = require("@project-serum/anchor");

  // provider is an abstraction of a connection to solana 
  const provider = anchor.Provider.local();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);
  const switchAccount = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
  // initial letter must be capital letter
  const program = anchor.workspace.Yourdappname;
```